# HTML/CSS - how to avoid image stretching

Tags: html, css

How can I ensure a background image does not stretch in html/css?

Below is the current code where the image behind a button looks like so:

```
#backImage6{
            /*@editable*/background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);
            /*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
            /*@editable*/background-position:top center;
            /*@editable*/background-size:auto 100%;
        }
```

[image]

If I change the background size to 100% 100%, then it looks like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
      <tr mc:repeatable="content" mc:variant="Image with CTA" id="backImage6">
        <td height="250">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center-on-narrow" role="presentation" style="display:table !important;" mc:edit="imagewithcta">
            <tr>
              <td class="button-td">
                <a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*">
                  <span class="button-link">
                    READ MORE
                  </span>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: don't stretch one of the dimensions beyond the other

Comment: Before answering your question - you should never have a table inside a table. This is really bad practice.

Comment: With `background-size: 100% 100%`, you got exactly what you asked for … if that is not what you want – then _what_ actually is? Are you perhaps looking for either one of the `contain` or `cover` keywords …?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `background-image`, you can add an image into a div and add `object-fit: cover;` to make it fit horizontally.

```css
#backImage6 {
  /*@editable*/
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);
  /*@editable*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*@editable*/
  background-position: top center;
  /*@editable*/
  background-size: auto 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.image-container {
  height: 250px;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="backImage6"></div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set background-size to contain.
your code will be like this:

```
#backImage6{
        /*@editable*/background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);
        /*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
        /*@editable*/background-position:top center;
        /*@editable*/background-size: contain;
    }
```

background-size: contain scales the image as large as possible within its container without cropping or stretching the image.
for more information take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size